# alias_method_chain fix for Devise with Rails 5 API?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Devise has been giving me this message `DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from <class:RouteSet> at /.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:27)` 
this is what the routes.rb for Devise looks like

```
module ActionDispatch::Routing
  class RouteSet #:nodoc:
    # Ensure Devise modules are included only after loading routes, because we
    # need devise_for mappings already declared to create filters and helpers.
    def finalize_with_devise!
      result = finalize_without_devise!

      @devise_finalized ||= begin
        if Devise.router_name.nil? && defined?(@devise_finalized) && self != Rails.application.try(:routes)
          warn "[DEVISE] We have detected that you are using devise_for inside engine routes. " \
            "In this case, you probably want to set Devise.router_name = MOUNT_POINT, where "   \
            "MOUNT_POINT is a symbol representing where this engine will be mounted at. For "   \
            "now Devise will default the mount point to :main_app. You can explicitly set it"   \
            " to :main_app as well in case you want to keep the current behavior."
        end

        Devise.configure_warden!
        Devise.regenerate_helpers!
        true
      end

      result
    end
    alias_method_chain :finalize!, :devise
  end
```

is a quick fix possible here?

Answer (score 3):

The devise release candidate supports Rails 5, throw this in the ol' Gemfile

`gem "devise", '~> 4.0.0.rc1'`

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following:

1) There is this gist with the updated code of the routes.rb file for Rails 5

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chbonser/devise/f05dd9dddb33cbc1739266637eafa2299661f517/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb

OR

2) Use the terminal in order to get the gem folder path:

```
gem environment
```

You should get the path, that will help you to locate the devise gem folder.

Browse to devise gem (something like this):

```
cd /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise
```

and edit/update file like failure_app.rb:

```
nano failure_app.rb
```

comment/remove RackDelegation reference:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3736

etc.

Comment: I saw that very same thread before and have tried removing RackDelegation reference, all it lead to was a message that `dynamic_matchers.rb:21:in `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)`